# Sci-fi story/novella which involves intelligent probe exchanging messages with a group of children, contact diminishes over time

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, novella

There's an artificial intelligence/computer/spacecraft flying away from Earth on a long mission. In the beginning, it exchanges messages with a group of children (I think it was 100), whose parents have paid to be part of this program.

As time goes on and years pass (decades), the amount of people who are still in contact diminishes and finally only one person (having lived their full lifespan) is still in contact with the ship.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's parents and children, not twins communicating despite the effects of relativity?

Comment: Sounds like a mash-up of "Time For The Stars" with something else.

Comment: The title sounded like Chocky

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The children(and later adults as they grow up)(well, one specific whose viewpoint is used in storytelling)are the ones sending messages.The parents never partake in this.